# Set null value in ternary operator in JMESPath?

Tags: jmespath

Is there a way to set a value to null with JMESPath? In my example, the value should be set to null if `qux_1` is not null and else the value should be set to the value of `baz`.

I thought the ternary operator could be read as if else condition but null would be evaluated as false?

```py
import jmespath

o = {
    "foo": {
        "bar": {"baz": 4321},
        "bar_1": {"baz_1": {"qux_1": 1234}}
    }
}
jmespath.search("(foo.bar_1.baz_1.qux_1 && null)||foo.bar.baz", o)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your actual attempt is that `` null || `some_value` `` will always yield `some_value`, because `null` is a falsy value (evaluates to `false` in a condition).

---

What you can do, here is to use a [filter projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections).
But, for that, you first need to have an array — which can be done via the function [`to_array`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-array).

Then, you just have to display `foo.bar.baz` if `foo.bar_1.baz_1.qux_1`:

```
to_array(@)[?foo.bar_1.baz_1.qux_1].foo.bar.baz
```

To come back to a single value, you'll need to [stop the projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions), then take the first element of the resulting array:

```
to_array(@)[?foo.bar_1.baz_1.qux_1].foo.bar.baz | [0]
```

---

Mind that this is a simple syntax, that could have some gotcha, e.g. if `foo.bar_1.baz_1.qux_1 == false` or `foo.bar_1.baz_1.qux_1 == null`, and then you need to adapt your condition to your exact use case:

For example:

```
to_array(@)[?foo.bar_1.baz_1.qux_1 != null].foo.bar.baz | [0]
```